# How do I graph an interation of functions based on [i] where each iteration is multiplied by the others?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a basic graph for a series of evenly spaced out high shelf filters here:

[image: Graph]
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wa0rd8migz

However, instead of graphing all the iterations of the function out, I would like them all multiplied together into one final function.

ie. g(x) = f0(x) * f1(x) * f2(x) * f3(x) ... * f15(x)

What is the correct way of writing this so it will graph this equation?

Comment: So you want $$ g(x) = \prod_{n=0}^{15} f_n (x)?$$ If so, enter `g(x) = \prod_{n=0}^{15} f_n (x)` into desmos.

Comment: Hi Brian, Yes in principle that's what I want, but I'm having trouble making my [i] series work for both. Here's what I've got in Desmos: https://i.postimg.cc/v86YR03q/graph-2.png   

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wa0rd8migz

How do I write the multiplicative function in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mfoomuj51v

Just needed to put it all in one expression.